# Service reference autogenerated code not executing as expected

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I have a problem inasmuch as my property setter in Reference.cs is not being executed. I am trying to set my property like this:

```
var rateOfExchangeParameters = new Service.getRateOfExchange()
{
    charterEnquiryId = 1550003668
};
```

but the property setter is returning without ever executing the RaisePropertyChanged method:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
public long charterEnquiryId {
    get {
        return this.charterEnquiryIdField;
    }
    set {
        this.charterEnquiryIdField = value; // returns after this
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("charterEnquiryId"); // never executed
    }
}
```

I have tried wrapping the first line of the setter in a try/catch block, but no exception is raised. This is causing a problem in my service call:

```
_ratesOfExchange = proxy.getRateOfExchange(rateOfExchangeParameters);
```

which fails because the parameter charterEnquiryId is not in the SOAP request. What am I doing wrong?

M

Comment: I'm not too flash hot with C#, but by calling this.charterEnquiryIdField, is that not creating a self-referencing loop? Or is there no need for private variables in C# properties?

Comment: The code you're referring to is automatically generated and is fine. The RaisePropertyChanged doesn't cause the charterEnquiryId to be reevaluated.